# A problem with truth tables

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I want to know how to justify the following fact:

For the truth value of  $(p \veebar  q)\rightarrow p $, isn't possible to deternine $V(q)$, that's to say, the truth value of $q$. I tried to justify it by using truth tables, but I don't know how to justify this properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general technique for demonstrating that information can't be retrieved is to provide two examples in which the provided data is the same, but the information in question is different. For example, $q$ can't be retrieved from $p \vee q$, because we have the two scenarios $V(p) = T$, $V(q) = T$ and $V(p) = T$, $V(q) = F$. In each scenario, $p \vee q$ is true; but $q$ has a different truth value in each case. You can use a similar approach for $(p \vee q) \to p$.